# Why is UIKit resetting the UIViewController's UIView frame to "full screen" during a custom transition?

Tags: uiview, ios7, uikit-transitions

I'm using a custom transition to slide a view controller 2/3 off screen when `- presentViewController:animated:completion:` is called and slide it back again when `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is called.

I'm also using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition attached to a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to slide the view controller.

All works well, except when calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, before:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
```

is called the frame of the view controller slid off screen is set to:

```
(0 0; 320 568)
```

causing it to momentarily "flash" before the animation runs and it slides from 2/3 off screen back to full screen.

By subclassing the UIView on the View Controller I can set a break point in `-setFrame` it shows the method:

```
[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]
```

is calling `-setFrame` with `(0 0; 320 568)`.

Why is it doing this? How can I prevent it from setting the frame before the animation starts?

Comment: did you find a solution? I came up with the same problem.  It looks like UIKit it applying the initial frame found in the transitionContext before executing any lines of code in the animateTransition method.